# How to open list form MFC Tree Control item?

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to open list form MFC Tree Control item. Something like in VC++ class view when you right click on some class it will display list of options.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a menu object. You can create a MENU resource using the Resource View in your project and then use the CMenu MFC class to popup that menu using the "CMenu::TrackPopupMenu" method.